# mkdir não cria o diretorio

Tags: php, mkdir

Mesmo eu tendo permissão, ele não cria o diretório e retorna "não criou".

```
<?php
$diretorio = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/LuckTor/arquivos/';
if (mkdir($diretorio . 'teste/', 777, true)) {
    echo 'criou';
} else {
    echo 'não criou';
}

echo 'q';
?>
```

Comment: Não aparece nenhum outro erro? Apenas "Não criouq"?

Comment: @AsuraKhan Antes aparecia em inglês "Esse diretório não existe ou não foi encontrado em", mas agora não aparece mais nada.

Comment: Tenta verificar a mensagem de erro [assim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/929490/1452488).

Comment: parece que o erro não tem a relação com esse trecho de código.

Comment: O erro retorna que eu não tenho permissão para criar a pasta, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: o mkdir não vai criar arquivo e sim um diretorio, ao que me parece é permissão de usuário já que a função [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php) retorna true ou false isso se o caminho existir por completo.

Comment: Lucas, ajustei mais detalhes da resposta, verifica se você consegue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas,

O comando **`mkdir`** tem os seguintes parâmetros caminho, modo e recursivo.

- Pergunta: O caminho C:/xampp/htdocs/LuckTor/arquivos/ exite?

Se tiver utilizando Windows o parâmetro modo é ignorado, tente assim:

```
mkdir ("C:/opt/xampp/htdocs/LuckTor/arquivos/teste");
```

Se você tiver utilizando Linux, tenta fazer dessa forma:

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir ("/opt/xampp/htdocs/LuckTor/arquivos/teste", 0777, true);
umask ($oldmask);
```

A primeira linha altera o umask para zero enquanto armazena o anterior em $ oldmask. A segunda linha faz com que o diretório use as permissões desejadas. A terceira linha restaura o umask para o que era originalmente.

Neste exemplo é indispensável que a variável **safe_mode** esteja desativada. Para alterar a diretiva safe_mode de um domínio na Revenda Linux, acesse o Plesk, clique sobre o domínio, vá em "Configuração" e, na linha (PHP 'safe_mode' on), desmarque apenas a opção "ON".

Mais informações:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions

Comment: Não funcionou tentando desta forma.

Comment: Lucas, ajustei mais detalhes da resposta, verifica se você consegue...